# While Loop While String is not Equal to Multiple Other Strings (Java)

Tags: java, while-loop, string-comparison

I am writing a method and would like to start the method with a comparison to see if a stored static string is equal to other words. Here it is in psuedocode:

```
While (String1 is neither equal to "A" nor "B" nor "C" nor "D")
{
    Print (Please enter a correct option);
    Take input;
}
```

Any help is great thanks.

Comment: Create a SET of of A, B, C, D and check `set.contains(string1)` in while loop

Comment: I would prefer to use a `do while loop`

Answer (score 3):

In your case, you have four admissible inputs namely `"A", "B", "C", "D"`. This can easily be implemented only using boolean operators; namely the loop condition is when your input is *neither* that of `"A"` nor `"B"` nor `"C"` nor `"D"`.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

System.out.println("Enter a selection (NOR): ");
String string1 = input.next();

while (    !string1.equals("A")
        && !string1.equals("B") 
        && !string1.equals("C") 
        && !string1.equals("D")) {
    System.out.println("Enter again (NOR): ");
    string1 = input.next();
}
input.close();
```

But what about situations where there are *arbitrarily but finitely many admissible inputs*, such as having all letters of the Hungarian alphabet? The set may be the best option.

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

// Either manually or use a method to add admissible values to the set
Set<String> admissible = new HashSet<String>();
admissible.add("A");
admissible.add("B");
admissible.add("C");
admissible.add("D");
// ... and so on. You can also use helper methods to generate the list of admissibles
// in case if it is in a file (such as a dictionary or list of words).

System.out.println("Enter a selection (Set): ");
String string1 = input.next();

// If input string1 is not found anywhere in the set
while (!admissible.contains(string1))  {
    System.out.println("Enter again (Set): ");
    string1 = input.next();
} 
input.close();
```

Comment: Also, which way would be the fastest: using booleans, using sets, or using regexes?

Comment: You can answer the performance question definitively only with a good benchmark. My bet would be that `!string1.equals("A") && !string1.equals("B") && ...` will be the most efficient for small number of elements. At some number the set will become better. I don't think regex will be the worst variant as it's essentially the same as `!string1.equals("A") && !string1.equals("B") && ...` but with some overhead.

Comment: Sure. Is it recommended that I should note that the first method, the "naive" or "plain" method using only booleans is the most recommended for small amount of elements? Or is the comment good enough?

Comment: Well, is it "the most recommended"? Do you have any proof of that? My comment is just my guess.

Comment: Then, even assuming it's the most efficient way - that does not make it recommended. I personally would prefer using set with the appropriate implementation.

Answer (score 1):

As Hemant stated in [their comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50356306/while-loop-while-string-is-not-equal-to-multiple-other-strings-java/50356414#comment87728917_50356306), it'd be smart to use a `Set` to store whatever `String`s you want to check against:

```
Set<String> words = Set.of("Hello", "World!");

while (!words.contains(string1)) {
    ...
}
```

**Note**: `Set#of` was introduced in Java 9, and `string1` is the `String` that you're checking against.

Answer (score 1):

```
// static set at top of the class
private static final Set<String> SET = new HashSet<>
                                (Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "D"));

void func() {

    String input = takeInput();
    while(!SET.contains(input)) {

        input = takeInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: Don't know why, but that uppercase `set` troubles me xD

Comment: It can be changed to meaningful name, since we don't know the context, we can't tell exact name of variable

Comment: @NiVeR Uppercase is fine for constants. What troubles me is a non-meaningful name `SET`.

Comment: @lexicore I was indeed referring to this. Uppercase for constants is perfectly fine.

Answer (score 1):

One approach is to construct a simple [regular expression](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#matches(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.CharSequence)) to match your strings:

```
String input = "";
while (!Pattern.matches("FirstString|SecondString|ThirdString", input)) {
    ...
}
```

Regular expression pattern is composed of the words that you wish to allow separated by the vertical bar `|` character.

**Note:** Using `while` loop requires setting `input` to a non-matching `String` before entering the loop. You can improve upon this by changing to `do` / `while` loop:

```
String input;
do {
    System.out.println("Please enter a correct option");
    input = takeInput();
} while (!Pattern.matches("FirstString|SecondString|ThirdString", input));
```

Comment: Would I have to import something for the pattern function?

Comment: @lexicore It depends on the benchmark. In cases where user input is required there would be no discernible difference even with a linear array search of 100+ items, even if it is performed by trained circus mice ;-)